Problem with Ubuntu 24.04 on VMware
I'm running VMPlayer 17.5 (latest) on Windows 11 and tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 on a new virtual machine. Installation showed some flickering and mouse was not usable but with keyboard input I managed to install. Started the installed image and tried to change window size using the app. VMPlayer froze and had to be killed using Windows Task Manager.
Same when I try to use file manager in Ubuntu. Firefox and Terminal work, though.
Never saw this behavior with Ubuntu 22.04 or other distributions.
How can I fix this?

I installed it under vmware, but it only started in "safe graphics" mode.

try on virtuabox!!

I tinkered around a bit and it is definitely caused by the new interface. Terminal runs fine as well as Firefox. But not the file manager or settings. Looks like some graphics driver problem and I will try to switch off 3d acceleration as proposed by Fedor.

It's the same problem using VMWare Workstation Pro 17.5.2 on Windows 11 and the latest Ubuntu 24.04 ISO. The only way round it, as suggested below, is to turn off "Accelerate 3D graphics" in the VM settings.

There is a solution to this here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515938/how-to-fix-freezing-ubuntu-24-04-on-vmware-and-enable-accelerated-graphics

I just installed 17.6.1 on 24.04.1 and it seemed to install ok. However, today I could not login. I rebooted a few times but it seems to stop booting at the Started gdm.service stage of booting. Disappointing.

On VMWare 17.5.1 I encountered the same problem: after starting Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and VMWare itself froze.
After several restart attempts, the following helped: switch off "Accelerate 3D graphics" on Display section of VM Hardware settings. At now all works fine.

Thanks I'll give it a try.

Thank you very much - that did it!

thanks that worked, had no idea why it was hanging and crashing.

To resolve the screen blacking out and unresponsiveness issue, you can update your graphics drivers using the oibaf PPA repository. Here are the steps:
Add the Graphics Drivers PPA:
Open a terminal in Ubuntu and add the PPA repository:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

Update and Upgrade
After adding the repository, update your package list and upgrade your system:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Apply changes
Reboot your Ubuntu virtual machine to apply the changes. Activate the hardware acceleration and start the machine.

This works for me. Thanks!

When I run glxinfo | grep OpenGL I get MESA-LOADER: failed to open vmwgfx: driver not built. The open-vm-tools are installed from apt.

Thanks! I turned off "Accelerate 3D graphics" like described above to get my system booting and then installed oibaf's drivers as described here.  After that, I could re-enable 3D acceleration.  Thanks!!

sudo apt install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop


Thanks but those are already installed automatically.

I encountered the same issue on VMWare on a Windows 11 host.
The only way to get out of this situation is to hit the windows reset-display-driver combo (Ctrl + Win + Shift + B), which forces gdm (or whatever you are using) to the login screen.
dmesg reports:
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] kauditd_printk_skb: 37 callbacks suppressed
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] audit: type=1400 audit(1714160303.067:49): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="rsyslogd" pid=2041 comm="apparmor_parser"
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] NET: Registered PF_PPPOX protocol family
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] l2tp_core: L2TP core driver, V2.0
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] l2tp_netlink: L2TP netlink interface
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] l2tp_ppp: PPPoL2TP kernel driver, V2.0
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] loop40: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] IPsec XFRM device driver
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] audit: type=1400 audit(1714160303.312:50): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2293 comm="apparmor_parser"
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] audit: type=1400 audit(1714160303.312:51): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=2293 comm="apparmor_parser"
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] audit: type=1400 audit(1714160303.601:52): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=2470 comm="apparmor_parser"
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:23 2024] evm: overlay not supported
[Fri Apr 26 21:38:24 2024] rfkill: input handler disabled

There is a similar post about overlay not supported that claims that the root cause is the display driver:
Boot problem after update - missing 'lowerdir'

I have also tried to install Ubuntu 24.04.1 on VMware workstation pro-17.5.2.
The new updated Kernal is not compatible with any version of VMware workstation pro, the new 17.6 version may work.
As Ubuntu have removed 22.04 from desktop downloads,
You can use this URL and scroll down to 22.04 desktop amd64 iso, this is compatible with vmware workstation Pro 17.52 and below.
https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04.1/
As long as you do not mind the older Ubuntu version, this works perfectly, even with Legacy Bios. Do Not press yes to upgrade to 24.04 when notified as it crashed my windows 10 pro and all my drives during Ubuntus update, it took six days to rebuild what Ubuntu upgrade caused.
