How to Fix Freezing Ubuntu 24.04 on VMware and Enable Accelerated Graphics
I'm running VMware Workstation Pro 17.5.1 on Windows 11 and tried to install Ubuntu 24.04 on a new virtual machine. During installation, I experienced screen flickering and the mouse was not usable. However, once installed, the VM froze when trying to resize the window or use the file manager.
Additionally, when the option for VMware Accelerated Graphics is enabled, the VM freezes. I can run Ubuntu without hardware acceleration enabled.
Solution:
To resolve the screen blacking out and unresponsiveness issue, you can update your graphics drivers using the oibaf PPA repository. Here are the steps:
Add the Graphics Drivers PPA:
Open a terminal in Ubuntu and add the PPA repository:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
Update and Upgrade:
After adding the repository, update your package list and upgrade your system:
sudo apt update
&& sudo apt upgrade
Reboot your Ubuntu virtual machine to apply the changes.
Activate the hardware acceleration and start the machine.

Many thanks! This worked for me on VMware Workstation Pro 17.5.2 on Windows11 with Ubuntu 24.04.

This is the solution to this question - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511670/problem-with-ubuntu-24-04-on-vmware

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While it is encouraged for users to answer their own question, Please Edit your question to be a question, then provide a answer. See Can I answer my own question?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

It may not be a question but it solved my problem. Very very useful!

This does not work... with Ubuntu 24.04.1 and VMware Workstation 17.5.2... installing the drivers results in a non-functioning system., So please beware.

With Ubuntu 24.04.1 and VMware Workstation 17.6.0 build-24238078 everything worked brilliantly. Many thanks!
